# How to configure .htaccess to bypass specific subdirectories?

Tags: .htaccess, drupal

I have three directories, Dir1,Dir2 & Dir3 in the root of my Drupal installation. I want to bypass these directories.

I have tried the below in .htaccess and its not working (Allowing subdirectories).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/Dir1/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/Dir2/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/Dir3/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have edit your .htaccess file by inserting the above code after the "RewriteEngine on" directive, before the Drupal rewrites.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/Dir1/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/Dir2/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/Dir3/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

And add [L] in the rewrite rule which tells it to stop there and bypass the rest of the rewrite rules.

Comment: To specifically prevent further rewriting you should use a hyphen (`-`) in the _substitution_, rather than rewrite to itself (which is less efficient and could fail in some situations). ie. `RewriteRule .* - [L]`